# How to make a SOAP/WSDL client in C#?

Tags: c#, soap, wsdl

I have been playing around in PHP with it and got something to work, what i did was:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://ws.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl");
$fetchedArr = $client->GetCityForecastByZIP(array("ZIP" => "10451")); //get the weather in the bronx YO!
```

And now i would like my application i WPF/C# to do the same. What is the equivalent in c#?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The simplest way is to use VS and add a web reference. This automatically creates the stub for you

Comment: Vote this one up!  **Add Service Reference** is the easiest way to go!

Comment: how to use a web service to give in xml data

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [WSDL tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6.aspx) to generate a C# file which will contain the necessary types and members to talk to the web service or you could add a Web Service reference. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms518533.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 4):

Adding web service reference to your project n making a call to the service exposed methods is your best bet . It does the trick n you're out of the hassle of creating SOAPs manually

Answer (score 4):

If your preferred approach is to control the generated code, it's best to use the more recent [SvcUtil.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/servicemodel-metadata-utility-tool-svcutil-exe) in place of Wsdl.exe.

See also [WCF proxy generation: svcutil.exe vs wsdl.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18313901/249742)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the "wsdl.exe" command from the .NET SDK to generate the wrapper classes if you don't want or like to use Visual Studio.

see:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.80%29.aspx