# How to implement WSDL provided by business partner?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wsdl

I have been provided to a wsdl file by another business to build webservice so that the other business can connect to service I build using the provided wsdl and xsd files. I am dot net developer using wcf. I want to know where to start having the wsdl and xsd files in hand.

Thanks

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2772708/how-to-make-a-soap-wsdl-client-in-c

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully, the schemas and WSDL are .NET friendly.  If you want to use WCF, you can generate your classes using [`SvcUtil.exe`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733.aspx).

```
svcutil -noconfig -serializer:datacontractserializer -d:../
 -namespace:*,MyCompany.Services.ServiceName wsdl.wsdl Messages.xsd Data.xsd
```

The bad news is that svcutil actually generates the client side proxy so you have to manually go and remove the client and channel classes.

For a full description of this approach see [Schema-based Development with Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335699.aspx).

In the article, they also talk about a Visual Studio add-in, [WSCF.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/), that allows you to do [Data contract generation](http://alexmg.com/post/2009/09/01/Data-contract-generation-is-now-available-in-WSCFblue.aspx) (among other contract first development tasks).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the .net [wsdl tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6%28VS.71%29.aspx) and [xsd tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28VS.71%29.aspx) to auto generate your classes.

Answer (score 0):

The quick and lazy way of doing it is simply to use add reference in VS (assuming .net3.5 +) or add web reference for .net 2; and allow VS to do the work.

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/a1647f10-9aa4-4b0c-bbd9-dfa51a9fab8e/adding-wcf-service-refere.aspx

As ( http://andrewtokeley.net/archive/2008/07/10/the-difference-between-ldquoadd-web-referencerdquo-and-ldquoadd-service-referencerdquo.aspx ) says its basically a wrapper for the functions the Tuzo and Ben added.

Makes life easier though and with the 'Add service wrapper' you can use the advanced settings to automatically generate ASync classes & Data Contracts.