# WCF proxy generation: svcutil.exe vs wsdl.exe

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy, wsdl, svcutil.exe

I have .wsdl and .xsd files from WebService and need to generate proxy by them. Svcutil.exe and wsdl.exe generate very different output. What is the difference between these two tools for proxy generation and which way is more preferable?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Svcutil and wsdl are two different technologies for generating a proxy for consuming your service. But wsdl.exe was made for old .NET 2.0 web services. It is like old version of svcutil. Svcutil allows you to generate proxies for both - web services and WCF services. For generating a proxy wsdl retieves the data by means of [DISCO discovery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc302073.aspx) protocol. Svcutil also supports DISCO. But it can make the proxy retrieval using [WS-Metadata Exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-MetadataExchange) protocol, which is an interopable standart of SOA.

I advice you to use svcutil because it would allow you to consume both .net 2.0 web services and wcf services.

Answer (score 0):

For what i know today wsdl is useful when you must generate a client code for an old version of the framework. For example when you have a codebase in NET 2.0 and you want call a WCF service.