# Can wsdl.exe generate the same files that Visual Studio does when adding a web reference?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, wsdl

### The Short, Short Version

Can [`wsdl.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx) generate the exact same files that Visual Studio does when adding a Web Reference?

#### Alternatively:

What are the Windows CMD commands that will mimic what Visual Studio does when adding a Web Reference?

### A Little More Detail

I have a VS2015 project that uses a Web Reference: https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_2_0/netsuite.wsdl (NetSuite - bleh).

I can add the Web Service reference in Visual Studio (Project -> Add Service Reference -> Advanced -> Add Web Reference -> Enter URL -> Add Reference) and it will generate a whole bunch of `.xsd` and `.datasource` files:

[image: Generated by Visual Studio]

Everything is useable and happy. Yay.

---

However, when I use `WSDL.exe`, it only generates a single file: `NetSuiteService.cs`:

```
C:\CSharpPlayground\CSharpPlayground>mkdir "Web References\com.netsuite.webservices"

C:\CSharpPlayground\CSharpPlayground>wsdl.exe /:"Web References\com.netsuite.webservices" "https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_2_0/netsuite.wsdl"
Microsoft (R) Web Services Description Language Utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Writing file 'C:\CSharpPlayground\CSharpPlayground\NetSuiteService.cs'.
```

I've poured over `wdsl.exe /?` and haven't found anything that looks like it would help me.

Is `wsdl.exe` not the right tool for the job?

### Background

I am trying to get CI builds working for my project (we self-host a [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/) instance, so I'm using gitlab-ci). The project builds just fine on my development computer because these `.xsd` and `.datasource` files all exist.

However, they don't exist on the build machine. I found that I can update the WSDL data using a MSBuild target/task thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159751/1354930). So I added that to my `.csproj` file and it successfully downloads the data from NetSuite - only to a single .cs file rather than the collection. Thus, the build fails.

I could simply check in all of the web reference files to git, but I'd rather not do that unless I absolutely have to.

### Update 1 (2017-03-13 15:56 PDT)

@RasmusW below mentioned the newer `scvutil.exe` utility. This gets part of the way there - it generates the individual `.xsd` files (the `.datasource` files [might not be needed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1439364/1354930)).

However, the generated `.xsd` files are not named correctly. They are using the `namespace` value rather than the `schemaLocation` value.

For example, in the .wsdl file provided by NetSuite we have:

```
<xsd:import namespace="urn:types.accounting_2015_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com" schemaLocation="https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/lists/v2015_2_0/accountingTypes.xsd"/>
```

The generated file is `types.accounting_2015_2.lists.webservices.netsuite.com.xsd` rather than `accountingTypes.xsd`.

In addition, there are other files generated by VS2015:

- **NetSuiteService.cs**

  - This I can get by using `wsdl.exe /out:"Web References\com.netsuite.webservices\\" https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2015_2_0/netsuite.wsdl`. It returns the exact same file as what VS2015 creates.
- **Reference.cs**

  - No idea what this really is or how it's generated. It appears to be very similar to what's in NetSuiteService.cs though.
- **Reference.map**

  - This is an xml file that has a bunch of `DiscoveryClientResult` items that map  a url to a filename. I assume that this is how Visual Studio gets the names for the .xsd files, but I'm not sure.
  - Looks something like: `<DiscoveryClientResult referenceType="System.Web.Services.Discovery.SchemaReference" url="https://webservices.netsuite.com/xsd/lists/v2015_2_0/accountingTypes.xsd" filename="accountingTypes.xsd" />`

Comment: Any particular reason that you want to use wsdl.exe and not svcutil.exe?    For the difference between wsdl.exe and svcutil.exe, you can check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311816/wcf-proxy-generation-svcutil-exe-vs-wsdl-exe

Comment: @RasmusW Because I wasn't aware of `svcutil.exe` :-)   A very cursory check of that tool results in the same thing - a single file being generated. I'm currently looking over the options to see if there are flags I can set.

Answer (score 1):

> Note: All of the below is specific to the WSDL file that I'm using ([NetSuite](https://webservices.netsuite.com/wsdl/v2016_2_0/netsuite.wsdl)), so it may not work for you. But hey, it's worth trying!

After some experimentation, this is what I've come up with to answer the question:

#### What are the Windows CMD commands that will mimic what Visual Studio does when adding a Web Reference?

1. VS makes the Web References folder and namespace folder. This needs to be done because the following steps do not necessarily create the folders for you. Note that you'll need to change your folder names accordingly. In this example, `com.netsuite.webservices` is the namespace that everything gets put in.

   ```
   SET OUR_DIR="%PROJECT_NAME%\Web References\com.netsuite.webservices"
   mkdir "%OUR_DIR%"
   ```
2. Use the [`WSDL.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(v=vs.100).aspx) tool to create the main `.cs` file.

   ```
   wsdl.exe /out:"%OUR_DIR%\NetSuiteService.cs" %WSDL_URL%
   ```

   > Note that we're using `wsdl.exe`, even though it's deprecated in favor of [`svcutil.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733(v=vs.110).aspx). This is because the two tools output different files when generating source code from the wsdl file. I don't know why this is - it may be specific to the wsdl file I'm using or it may be for another reason.
3. Create the `.xsd` files with the [`disco.exe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy2a3ybs(v=vs.100).aspx) tool. Hehe fun name.

   ```
   disco.exe /out:"%OUR_DIR%" %WSDL_URL%
   ```

   This generates the individual `.xsd` files that were shown in the screenshot in the question above. It also creates the map file that maps names to make things pretty (see Update 1 in question). However, I haven't been able to figure out how to change the output name of the mapfile (default is `results.discomap`), so I just do it manually:

   ```
   move "%OUR_DIR%\results.discomap" "%OUR_DIR%\Reference.map"
   ```

The above steps give you *almost* everything - the files match exactly what Visual Studio (2015) creates, but `Reference.cs` is still missing. This file appears to be very similar to the WSDL-generated code `NetSuiteService.cs` but puts everything in the namespace from step 1 (the folder, `com.netsuite.webservices`).

Sadly I haven't been able to figure out how to generate this `Reference.cs` file.

My only solution was to generate this file on my dev machine, copy it to somewhere I can easily access, and then download/copy it to the build folder during CI builds. For example, I put it in the `C:\Utilities` folder on the build machine, so I can pull it in with

```
copy "C:\Utilities\NetSuite_DO_NOT_DELETE__Reference.cs" "%OUR_DIR%\Reference.cs"
```